# The system time has changed kernel-general, off by one day

Tags: windows-7, kernel, time

Random events showing in event log.  The system time changes to tomorrow, and then corrects about 10-15 seconds later.  Causing all sorts of temproary havoc w/ VPN, Outlook, etc. Any thoughts?

Comment: This ended up being poorly implemented software that was changing the system time, temporarily, and then resetting.  The fact that it was one day off was coincidental because it set the day to 14.  This was happening on a developers machine and fortunately he remembered seeing code that changed the system time in one of the applications he was debugging.

Comment: Are you asking about Windows Event Log entries that read `The system time has changed to…`? If so, then it may not be abnormal. Check the event around it. Are there any `Kernel-General` or `Power-Troubleshooter` events that mention entering or resuming from sleep? When you sleep a system then wake it up, it notices that the time has suddenly jumped, and just logs it (and performs any necessary time-sensitive action). The event simply notes that the time has changed since the last time the system was on (which makes sense since time does not stop), not that the system clock has been altered.

Answer (score 2):

Is this running in a virtual-machine?   It is not uncommon to have "RTC" (realtime clock) issues in a virtual machine, especially when the correct virtual-tools package isn't installed.  It is also possible that the server is polling time from a bad source.  More information about the server would be helpful.